# Control Functions: First stage residual has (close to) same magnitude and significance and opposite sign as endogenous variable

Tags: instrumental-variables

I am implementing a standard control function regression.  I start with the equations:

$y_1 = \alpha \; y_2 +  X \beta + \varepsilon$

$y_2 = \gamma z +  X \beta + \nu$

$y_2$ is endogenous in the first equation, $X$ contains exogenous predictors, and $z$ is my exogenous instrument.  Technically, the first equation is an OLS, whereas the second is a logit, though I'm not certain if that is super relevant here.  I use simple replacement bootstrapping to calculate the errors on this two-stage model.

I get my residuals from the regression of $y_2$ on predictors then run the following version of the regression for $y_1$:

$y_1 = \alpha \; y_2 + \delta \hat{\nu} +  X \beta + \varepsilon$.

I know that I can use a significance test on $\hat{\delta}$ in the second stage equation to test whether $y_2$ is indeed endogenous. (i.e. see Wooldridge, Panel Data, 2010, p.126ff).

In my particular situation, I am frequently observing that $\hat{\alpha}$ and $\hat{\delta}$ are very similar - namely, they are quite similar in magnitude and statistical significance, but just opposite in their sign.  This effect persists across a variety of formulations in my models (e.g. changing composition of $X$, varying sample composition, etc.).

Is this a very normal occurrence?  Is there any reason that this should give me pause, either regarding the validity of my instrument or somehow my implementation of the control function approach?